# Using str_extract in R to extract a number before a substring with regex

Tags: r, regex, tidyverse, stringr

I would like to use str_extract in the stringr package to extract the numbers from strings in the form `XX nights etcetc`.

I'm currently doing this:

```
library(stringr)

str_extract("17 nights$5 Days", "(\\d)+ nights")
```

but that returns

`"17 nights"`

instead of `17`.

How can I extract just the number? I thought specifying the extract group with parentheses would work, but it doesn't.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use the look ahead regular express `(?=)`

```
library(stringr)

str_extract("17 nights$5 Days", "(\\d)+(?= nights)")
```

(\d) -  a digit
(\d)+ - one or more digits
(?= nights) - that comes in front of " nights"

The look behind `(?<=)` can also come in handy.

A good reference cheatsheet is from [Rstudio's website](https://www.rstudio.com/resources/cheatsheets/): https://raw.githubusercontent.com/rstudio/cheatsheets/main/regex.pdf

Comment: better if it's `(\\d+)` or `\\d+`

Answer (score 5):

In base R, we can use `sub` to extract number which comes before `"nights"`

```
as.integer(sub("(\\d+)\\s+nights.*", "\\1","17 nights$5 Days"))
#[1] 17
```

Or if the number is always the first number in the string we can use `readr::parse_number`

```
readr::parse_number("17 nights$5 Days")
#[1] 17
```

Comment: I just ran a check and using base R `as.integer(sub("(\\d+)\\s+nights.*", "\\1","17 nights$5 Days"))` (even with the `as.integer`) is about 3X faster than the equivalent `stringr`

Comment: Thanks for for readr::parse_number -- this is quite foolproof

Answer (score 4):

If you want to specify a specific group for return, use str_replace(). The pattern you want to capture is wrapped in (), then in the replacement argument you refer to that group as "\\1" as it is capture group number one.

I added the ^ to indicate you want numbers only at the beginning of the string.

```
library(stringer)

str_replace(string = "17 nights$5 Days",
            pattern = "(^\\d+).*",
            replacement = "\\1")
```

giving:

```
[1] "17"
```

Comment: This is much slower (X2+) than just using extract.

Comment: @Moohan No doubt. I put it here because the original poster wanted to use numbers to refer to groups, which I don't think you can do in extract.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `stringr::str_match` which returns all of the matched groups as a matrix then select the correct column.

```
library(stringr)

str_match("17 nights$5 Days", "(\\d+?) nights")[[2]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Using rebus.
If the string always start with a number:

```r
library(stringr)
library(rebus)

pattern = START %R% one_or_more(DGT)
str_extract("17 nights$5 Days", pattern)
#> [1] "17"
```

<sup>Created on 2021-05-30 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>